# App icons are displayed incorrectly on the Force Quit window!

Tags: macos, force-quit

The app icons in the "Force Quit" window are displaying incorrectly. I have seen this issue on various macOS versions, including Monterey, Big Sur, Catalina, and Mojave:

I have reset my MacBook to the factory settings (Erased) and reinstalled macOS again, and I did an NVRAM reset as well, but the issue still persists!

Here is a screenshot of my "Force Quit":

[image]

Why are the app icons in the "Force Quit" window displaying incorrectly?

Comment: Hi! You will likely get a good answer or two if you ask a specific question at the end of your post. Also - some people may be skeptical what factory reset you performed since Code and Chrome are not part of the factory build on macOS. If you could document how you did that / what guide / how you came to get apps installed, perhaps we can help you out.

Comment: I just reset to the factory settings (erased) and reinstalled macOS again. 
You're right! These issues affect third-party apps: like VsCode, Chrome, iTerm2, and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Mac can run Ventura, the 14.1 is out and it might be a great time to take a backup and then erase the disk and install and test without bringing any third party apps or user settings back.

Then I would install only one app and test. Once you’re sure you have a few apps and things are good, you can [erase user content](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212749) and then run a restore to bring your user folder back but keep the working OS you know works.

Something different might be needed if you can’t or won’t run an OS with a sealed system volume.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/security/signed-system-volume-security-secd698747c9/web
- https://eclecticlight.co/2020/11/30/is-big-surs-system-volume-sealed/